# Passing string over urls django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm having trouble in understanding this error in my code, first let me try and explain what is happening and what I'm I trying to do.

My code is designed to load up 45 separate text files into an array, including the weight of each word/phrase and the word phrase itself. This has to occur at the beginning, before any description is received.

Second, once the description is received, it is parsed by my software into words/phrases, which are compared to the words/phrases in the array.

Third, my software then provides the top three classes, in rank order (first/second/third) by number, along with the score for each class.

I've made a django application that will serve this code, so I have a form which will provide two parameters classes and description, like this:

```
class TrademarkClassifierForm(forms.Form):
    """
    TODO: This forms will cover the questions the
    initial classifier program does
    :returns: TODO
    """
    classes = forms.CharField(max_length=10,
                              label="Test all trademark classes? Type 'yes' to do so or else enter the class to be tested ")
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TrademarkClassifierForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

Then I want to pass this two parameters in the `view` over the `url` like this:

```
class TrademarkClassifierResultView(FormView):
    """
    TODO: Post should redirect to it's on page with GET,
    specify set values in some query parameters,
    something like ?classes=yes&name=NameOfTrademarkClass
    This should be visible on results page.
    :param: classes
    :param: description
    :returns: TODO - params
    """
    template_name = 'trademark.html'
    form_class = TrademarkClassifierForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        classes = str(self.request.GET.get('classes'))
        description = str(self.request.GET.get('description'))
        form = TrademarkClassifierForm(initial={'classes': classes, 'description': description})
        context_data = self.get_context_data(classes, description, form=form)
        return self.render_to_response(context_data)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        classes = form.cleaned_data['classes']
        description = form.cleaned_data['description']
        return redirect(self.get_success_url(classes, description))

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR,
                             "Invalid data. Please check fields.")
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form)
        )

    def get_success_url(self, classes=None, description=None):
        return reverse("classifier:trademark") + "?classes=" + str(classes) + "&description" + str(description)

    def get_context_data(self, classes, description, **kwargs):
        context = super(TrademarkClassifierResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['classes'] = classes
        context['description'] = description
        context['trademark'] = ClassifyMarkBased.control_program(classes, description)
        return context
```

Now my problem is this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/trademark/

Django Version: 1.11.2
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'classifier',
 'crispy_forms',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'debug_toolbar']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/petar/.virtualenvs/trademark/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/petar/.virtualenvs/trademark/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/petar/.virtualenvs/trademark/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/petar/.virtualenvs/trademark/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/petar/.virtualenvs/trademark/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/petar/Documents/Synergy/Trademark/TM_base/classifier/views.py" in get
  60.         context_data = self.get_context_data(classes, description, form=form)

File "/home/petar/Documents/Synergy/Trademark/TM_base/classifier/views.py" in get_context_data
  82.         context['trademark'] = ClassifyMarkBased.control_program(classes, description)

File "/home/petar/Documents/Synergy/Trademark/TM_base/classifier/services/classify_mark_based.py" in control_program
  89.             N = len(word_count_array_for_all_classes[i])

Exception Type: IndexError at /trademark/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

This is my url:
`url(r'^trademark/', TrademarkClassifierResultView.as_view(), name="trademark"),`

and this is the part of the code that should calculate the trademark over this two parameters:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import re
import requests


class TrademarkService(object):
    # coding: utf-8

    # In[5]:


    # compare input string to a class
    # for words not found,look in a dictionary - add to text files for trademark words


    # In[6]:


    # open each trademark class file and read the words/frequency back into an array
    @staticmethod
    def open_file_read_words(file_name):
        unique_words_and_count_not_format = []

        tm_word_count_array = []
        my_list = []
        all_possible_entries = 1

        with open(file_name) as f:
            lines = [line.strip() for line in open(file_name)]
        all_possible_entries = len(lines)

        tm_word_count_array = [[0 for x in range(2)] for y in range(all_possible_entries)]
        i = 0
        while i < all_possible_entries:
            tm_word_count_array[i] = lines[i].split(',', 1)

            i += 1

        i = 0
        while i < all_possible_entries:
            tm_word_count_array[i][0] = int(tm_word_count_array[i][0])
            i += 1

        return tm_word_count_array

    # In[7]:


    # this section normalizes word frequency by the number of words x 1000
    @staticmethod
    def normalize_array(tm_word_count_array):
        list_of_freqs = []
        max_entries = len(tm_word_count_array)
        list_of_freqs = [0 for y in range(max_entries)]

        i = 0
        while i < max_entries:
            list_of_freqs[i] = tm_word_count_array[i][0]
            i += 1

        max_value = max(list_of_freqs)

        i = 0
        while i < max_entries:
            tm_word_count_array[i][0] = ((float(tm_word_count_array[i][0])) / max_entries) * 1000
            i += 1

        return tm_word_count_array

    # In[8]:


    # include the list of not useful words here
    @staticmethod
    def find_not_useful_words(word):
        not_useful_words = (
        "about", "are", "upon", "-", " ", "up", "other", "or", "not", "namely", "more", "made", "in", "for", "except",
        "but", "being", "all", "against", "was", "were", "will", "that", "its", "on", "it", "at", "was", "our", "your",
        "ours", "yours", "their", "them", "other", "out", "having", "have", "has", "in", "be", "than", "use", "uses",
        "using", "", "by", "and", "an", "a", "use", "used", "using", "for", "to", "of", "-)", "-]", "with", "as", "in",
        "the", "from")
        for test_word in not_useful_words:
            if word == test_word:
                return False
        return True

    # In[9]:


    # clean up the phrases by removing problematic characters
    @staticmethod
    def clean_up_phrases(data):
        important_words = ''
        word = data

        for c in word:
            if 0 <= ord(c) <= 127:
                # this is an ascii character.
                not_a_variable = 0
            else:

                if ord(c) == 201:
                    word = word.replace(c, "e")
                elif ord(c) == 241:
                    word = word.replace(c, "n")
                elif ord(c) == 225:
                    word = word.replace(c, "a")
                elif ord(c) == 251:
                    word = word.replace(c, "u")
                elif ord(c) == 8206:
                    word = word.replace(c, "")
                else:
                    word = word.replace(c, "")


                    # continue_yes=raw_input("do you want to continue?")

        word = word.lower()

        word = str(filter(lambda ch: ch not in "?.!/;:,'()[]", word))

        # calls the function above to remove words that were found to interfere with classification

        if data.find_not_useful_words(word):
            if len(word) > 1:
                important_words += word

        return important_words

    # In[10]:


    # find the important words in the string
    @staticmethod
    def find_important_words(data):

        all_entries = len(data)

        important_words = []

        for word in data.split():

            for c in word:
                if 0 <= ord(c) <= 127:
                    # this is an ascii character.
                    not_a_variable = 0
                else:

                    if ord(c) == 201:
                        word = word.replace(c, "e")
                    elif ord(c) == 241:
                        word = word.replace(c, "n")
                    elif ord(c) == 225:
                        word = word.replace(c, "a")
                    elif ord(c) == 251:
                        word = word.replace(c, "u")
                    elif ord(c) == 8206:
                        word = word.replace(c, "")
                    else:
                        word = word.replace(c, "")

            word = word.lower()

            word = str(filter(lambda ch: ch not in " ?.!/;:,'()[]", word))

            if word.endswith("-"):
                word = word[:-1]

            if word.startswith("-"):
                word = word[:1]

            if data.find_not_useful_words(word):
                if len(word) > 1:
                    important_words.append(word)

        return important_words

    # In[11]:

    @staticmethod
    def analyze_each_line_test_data(test_sentence, N, normalized_tm_word_count_array):
        # remove problematic characters and words, plus find important words/phrases
        test_important_phrases = test_sentence.clean_up_phrases(test_sentence)
        i = 0
        total_found = 0
        total_TM_class_count = 0
        total_TM_words_matched = []

        # score the trademark phrases in the string
        while i < N:
            count_phrases = 0
            if len(normalized_tm_word_count_array[i][1].split()) > 1:

                if test_important_phrases.find(normalized_tm_word_count_array[i][1]) > -1:
                    total_TM_words_matched.append(normalized_tm_word_count_array[i][1])
                    total_TM_class_count += (normalized_tm_word_count_array[i][0])
                    total_found += 1

            i += 1

        # decompose the string and remove extraneous words, then score the words in the string
        test_important_words = test_sentence.find_important_words(test_sentence)

        i = 0
        while i < N:
            count_words = 0
            if test_important_words.count(normalized_tm_word_count_array[i][1]) > 0:
                total_TM_words_matched.append(normalized_tm_word_count_array[i][1])
                count_words = test_important_words.count(normalized_tm_word_count_array[i][1])
                total_TM_class_count += (normalized_tm_word_count_array[i][0] * count_words)
                total_found += 1
            i += 1

        i = 0
        normalized_tm_word_count_values = [0 for y in range(N)]
        normalized_tm_word_count_words = ['a' for y in range(N)]
        while i < N:
            normalized_tm_word_count_values[i] = normalized_tm_word_count_array[i][0]
            normalized_tm_word_count_words[i] = normalized_tm_word_count_array[i][1]
            i += 1

        total_words_to_match = len(test_important_words) + len(test_important_phrases)
        not_found_words = list(set(test_important_words) - set(normalized_tm_word_count_words))
        return total_found, total_TM_words_matched, not_found_words, total_TM_class_count

    # In[12]:


    @staticmethod
    def open_class_file_read_words_to_array(file_name, file_name_class=None):
        tm_word_count_array = []
        tm_word_count_array = file_name.open_file_read_words(file_name_class)
        return tm_word_count_array

    # In[13]:


    # create a file for the trademark results
    @staticmethod
    def create_results_file(file_name, results_array, description):
        unique_words_and_count_not_format = []
        unique_words_and_count_to_write = []

        open_file_name = open(file_name, 'a')
        open_file_name.write("New trademark comparison")
        open_file_name.write("\n")
        open_file_name.write(description)
        open_file_name.write("\n")

        unique_words_and_count_to_write = np.array(results_array, dtype=object)

        np.savetxt(open_file_name, unique_words_and_count_to_write, fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
        open_file_name.write("\n")
        open_file_name.write("\n")
        open_file_name.write("\n")
        open_file_name.close()

    # In[14]:


    # this section controls the program
    @staticmethod
    def control_the_program(classes, description):
        description = []
        word_count_array_for_all_classes = []
        correct_class_set = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17',
                             '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33',
                             '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45']

        # depending on the answer, only one class worth of trademark words will be loaded up or else all will be loaded up
        # test_all_classes = raw_input(
        #     "Test all trademark classes? Type 'yes' to do so or else enter the class to be tested ")
        test_all_classes = classes

        # test description of goods/services
        # test_data_array = raw_input("Provide the description of goods or services ")
        test_data_array = description
        # file_name_data = raw_input("Provide the identifier for the results file ")

        # this file has the output of the classification engine, including the top 3 results
        # file_name_results = 'user_test_comparison_results_' + file_name_data + '.txt'

        # call to a program to open each file of trademark words in turn and read the words back into an array
        if test_all_classes == 'yes':
            i = 1
            number_classes_to_check = 45
            word_count_array_for_all_classes = [[] for z in range(46)]
            temp_array = []
            while i <= 45:
                # opens each file with the trademark words
                file_name_class = 'counted_phrases_class' + str(i) + '.txt'
                temp_array = classes.open_class_file_read_words_to_array(file_name_class)
                # normalization is used because some classes have many words and some have few words
                # the words/phrases are weighted according to frequency
                word_count_array_for_all_classes[i] = classes.normalize_array(temp_array)

                i += 1

        else:
            # print "you didn't enter yes"
            pass

        # length_test_data_array = len(test_data_array)
        # open(file_name_results, 'a').close()
        # start_writing_results = open(file_name_results, 'a')
        # start_writing_results.write("The start of the test")
        # start_writing_results.write("\n")
        # start_writing_results.write("Total number of potential items to match ")
        # start_writing_results.write(str(length_test_data_array))
        # start_writing_results.write("\n")
        # start_writing_results.close()

        top_result = [0 for y in range(2)]
        second_result = [0 for y in range(2)]
        third_result = [0 for y in range(2)]
        top_array_words_not_found = []
        second_array_words_not_found = []
        third_array_words_not_found = []

        counter_for_9vs42 = 0
        counter_for_data_errors = 0

        top_result = [0 for y in range(2)]
        second_result = [0 for y in range(2)]
        third_result = [0 for y in range(2)]
        top_array_words_not_found = []
        second_array_words_not_found = []
        third_array_words_not_found = []

        actual_class_results = [0 for y in range(2)]
        overall_array_results = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(4)]
        actual_class_words_not_found = []
        i = 1
        while i <= 45:
            total_found = 0
            total_TM_words_matched = 0
            not_found_words = ['']
            score = 0
            N = len(word_count_array_for_all_classes[i])
            total_found, total_TM_words_matched, not_found_words, score = classes.analyze_each_line_test_data(test_data_array, N,
                                                                                                              word_count_array_for_all_classes[i])

            if int(score) > 0:
                if int(score) > top_result[0]:
                    third_result[0] = second_result[0]
                    third_result[1] = second_result[1]
                    third_array_words_not_found = second_array_words_not_found
                    second_result[0] = top_result[0]
                    second_result[1] = top_result[1]
                    second_array_words_not_found = top_array_words_not_found
                    top_result[0] = int(score)
                    top_result[1] = i
                    top_array_words_not_found = ['']
                    top_array_words_not_found = not_found_words
                elif int(score) > second_result[0]:
                    third_result[0] = second_result[0]
                    third_result[1] = second_result[1]
                    third_array_words_not_found = second_array_words_not_found
                    second_result[0] = int(score)
                    second_result[1] = i
                    second_array_words_not_found = ['']
                    second_array_words_not_found = not_found_words

                elif int(score) > third_result[0]:
                    third_result[0] = int(score)
                    third_result[1] = i
                    third_array_words_not_found = ['']
                    third_array_words_not_found = not_found_words

            i += 1

        overall_array_results[0][0] = top_result[0]
        overall_array_results[0][1] = top_result[1]
        overall_array_results[0][2] = top_array_words_not_found
        overall_array_results[1][0] = second_result[0]
        overall_array_results[1][1] = second_result[1]
        overall_array_results[1][2] = second_array_words_not_found
        overall_array_results[2][0] = third_result[0]
        overall_array_results[2][1] = third_result[1]
        overall_array_results[2][2] = third_array_words_not_found

        # all results - including the first, second, third choices of the engine and the original description - are written to the file
        # create_results_file(file_name_results, overall_array_results, test_data_array)

        # start_writing_results = open(file_name_results, 'a')
        # start_writing_results.write("The end of the test")
        # start_writing_results.write("\n")
        #
        # start_writing_results.write("\n")
        # start_writing_results.write("\n")
        # start_writing_results.close()
        # print "finished the process"
```

From the code that I've provided you can see that this parameters where provided over python `raw_input` and after calculation code was creating a file in which you can read about the result.

I've rewritten this so I can serve it over the django application, so parameters `classes` and `description` should overwrite the `raw_input` and the result will be displayed in the template, like this:

```
{{ trademark.overall_array_results.top_result }}<br>
{{ trademark.overall_array_results.second_result }}<br>
{{ trademark.overall_array_results.third_result }}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing the write thing here, so I need help to understand this better, can someone help me to over come error.

Comment: I'd start with printing things at each step and verifying code vs expected output, starting with line `N = len(word_count_array_for_all_classes[i])`

Comment: Ok, I'm on to this, trying to debug the code

Comment: Does `TrademarkAnalyzeEachLineTestData.analyze_each_line_test_data` mutate  `word_count_array_for_all_classes[i]`?

Comment: Well I just found out that it does not do that, so I'm trying to fix it

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil, I've updated the question with the whole portion of the code that I'm using or the calculation

Comment: Not related to your problem, but if you have a class containing nothing but static methods, that's a sign you shouldn't be using a class at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `classes` is not "yes", then `word_count_array_for_all_classes` remains an empty list.

Comment: I'm back, as always thanks for the hint, I overlooked that